# How to access Azure blob storage via Flex Application?

Tags: flex4, azure

I am trying to access Blob Storage on Azure via my flex Application. I am doing this via an HTTP Service by using the url given by Azure Blob Storage. However, my storage has private and restricted access  and I can only update the storage by using the key (provided by Azure).
Since my application needs to write to this storage, I somehow need to pass in the key via my HTTPService? 
  Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Regards
Aparna